# Eclipse plugin: overriding standard command handler

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-pde

I'm trying to override an existing command handler in Eclipse. Specifically, I want to override the Run command (org.eclipse.debug.ui.commands.RunLast) so that it first terminates the process from the previous launch before starts the new one. I read [this article](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/157754/), wrote a handler and associated it with the Run command:

```xml
<extension point="org.eclipse.ui.handlers">
    <handler commandId="org.eclipse.debug.ui.commands.RunLast"
             class="net.anggo.tnr.TnRHandler">
        <activeWhen>
            <with variable="activeContexts">
                <iterate operator="or">
                    <equals value="net.anggo.tnr.TnREnabled"></equals>
                </iterate>
            </with>
        </activeWhen>
    </handler>
</extension>
```

I added `activeWhen` clause so that the new handler has a higher priority than the default handler. I activated TnREnabled context in an `IStartup`. But still, the default handler is run when I hit the Run menu item. I assume this is because the priority of the default handler is still higher than that of the new one. So my question is..

How can I calculate the priority of the default handler so that I can compare it with that of the new handler? Does my assumption seem correct that it is a priority issue? Is there a diagnostic way I can see what the problem is e.g. plugin spy? I'd appreciate any of help.

Comment: Debug still uses the old style `org.eclipse.ui.actionSets` action to define an action for the command. I'm not sure if you can override that.

Comment: @greg-449 You seem right :/ Thanks.