# How To Replace Default Handler

Tags: eclipse-plugin

The JFace `PreferenceDialog` used by us has a bug, where the exceptions thrown by `IPersistentPreferenceStore#save()` are not handled and the dialog just closes without the user realizing something has gone wrong.

So I created my own implementation of the class that fixes this problem and "just" need to somehow replace the default handler defined by the command `org.eclipse.ui.window.preferences`.

Normally I'd do something like this:

```xml
<extension point="org.eclipse.ui.activities">
  <activity id="org.acme.preference.oldPreferenceDialog" name="Remove Preference Dialog">
      <enabledWhen>
          <with variable="selection">
              <count value="-1" />
          </with>
      </enabledWhen>
  </activity>
  <activityPatternBinding
        activityId="org.acme.preference.oldPreferenceDialog"
        isEqualityPattern="true"
        pattern="org.eclipse.ui/org.eclipse.ui.window.preferences" />
  </activityPatternBinding>
</extension>
```

Which somehow works perfectly for every command but the above. But even if it did work it wouldn't do what I want - I still want to have the command, I only want to disable the handler, but handlers don't have an ID (much less the ones defined in the "defaultHandler" attribute of the commands.

Is there something I can do to replace the preference dialog / default handler of a command?

Comment: Did you try to use a custom [context](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Fguide%2Fworkbench_advext_contexts.htm) to activate your handler, like described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28132938/eclipse-plugin-overriding-standard-command-handler) and [here](http://www.mindfiresolutions.com/Using-custom-handlers-for-standard-commands-in-Eclipse-RCP-726.php)?

Comment: @RüdigerHerrmann I did now, and it works. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A custom [context](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Fguide%2Fworkbench_advext_contexts.htm) can be used to override a handler.

If you specify the `activeWhen` clause of your handler like this

```xml
<activeWhen>
  <with variable="activeContexts">
    <iterate operator="or">
      <equals value="myContext" /equals>
    </iterate>
  </with>
</activeWhen>
```

the custom handler will take precedence whenever `myContext` is active.

If - like in your case - the custom handler should always take precedence, I recommend to activate the context in the plug-in's Activator.